# Authentication flow in React JS confusion

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, token

I have a react app where when I login I save the userInfo and token in redux store. Also, I save the token only in a Cookie.

My problem is when I refresh everything in the redux is gone. So, my question is how do I manage the userInfo? Do I store it also in Cookie ?

so for example when the user enter the url of the website and has the token checked if in cookie to go to the Home page automatically and the userInfo will be there.

I appreciate your help everyone. Have a nice day :)

Comment: have you tried `redux-persist` it can re-hydrates your store after page refresh